# Linear independence or dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following vectors in the matrix are linear dependent, and I am just wondering how that is determined. Do you need to bring it to REF? and if so how do you do that?

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 2& 4\\2&1&-1&3\\ -2&0&1&2\\\end{bmatrix}$$

this turns out to be linear dependent and I am not sure why, when I brought it to REF I got

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 2& 4\\0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&5&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

making the vectors linear independent

Answer (score 0):

You showed that you can make $(1,0,0)$ out of the vectors (that's the first one in REF form). So you can also make $(3,1,0) - 3 \times (1,0,0)$, which is the second minus thrice the first; that is, you can also make $(0,1,0)$.

Finally, you can make $0$ from $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(4,1,0)$.

Generally, if you have more than $n$ vectors of length $n$, then they're dependent. Indeed, in $F^n$ any $n$ linearly independent vectors form a basis, so the $n+1$th vector must be dependent on the rest.

Comment: but doesnt my matrix show that x1,x2,x3,x4=0?

Comment: or do I need to get it to RREF which is not possible

Comment: @user123 What are $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$?

Answer (score 0):

The echelon form you got tells you that the vectors are linearly dependent, which was known in advance anyway, because four vectors in a three-dimensional vector space are necessarily dependent.

On the other hand, the REF is not right. Let's see:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 3 &  2 & 4 \\
 2 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
-2 & 0 &  1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  3 &  2 &  4 \\
0 & -5 & -5 & -5 \\
0 &  6 &  5 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2-2R_1 \\ R_3&\gets R_3+2R_1\end{aligned}
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 &  4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
0 & 6 & 5 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_2\gets-\tfrac{1}{5}R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 &  4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3-6R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 &  4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3-6R_2
\end{align}
In order to find one vector as a linear combination of the others, one can go on to the RREF:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 &  4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 12 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2-R_3 \\ R_1&\gets R_1-2R_3\end{aligned}
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_1\gets R_1-3R_2
\end{align}
This says that the last column as the linear combination of the first three columns, with coefficients $-3$, $5$ and $-4$. Since row operations don't change the linear relations, the same happens for the original vectors. Indeed
$$
-3\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-2\end{bmatrix}
+5\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
-4\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}4\\3\\2\end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I know your REF is wrong? The REF is not unique, because it depends on the method you use; but the RREF *is* unique and the RREF one gets from
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 2& 4\\0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&5&0\\\end{bmatrix}
is different from the above.